# C struct, function pointer, and header problems (unsure which is the cause)

Tags: c, struct, binary-tree, function-pointers, header-files

So, I'm trying to make this binary tree program in C and it just keeps throwing the darndest compile errors.  Whenever I change something to find what is causing the error, it changes!  I have not forgotten my include guards, I used #pragma once.  If I place the struct in the header I get incompatible types, if I put it in the .c I get a redefinition of pretty_print which goes away when I rename pretty_print.  As I trim out the other functions in bintree.c and the header, the error changes to intTree being undefined.  If I then change intTree to just int it becomes incompatible types.  This goes away if I merge the header into the .c. Now it's gone.  I think these might be seperate errors and the changing error might be my bad, but it is happening an I have no idea why.  I will present code that demonstrates as many of these, but whenever I try to duplicate what I did it throws a different error.  But I'm not frustrated.  I would like to be able to post a well-formatted question with helpful information, but I have none, despite spending several hours on this program.

bintree.cxx

```
#include "bintree.h"

int add(intTree* root,int key,void* val){
    if(!root){
        root=malloc(sizeof(intTree));
        if(!root){
            return 1;
        }
        root->key=key;
        root->val=val;
        root->left=0;
        root->right=0;
        return 0;
    }
    if(key>root->key){
        if(root->right){
            return add(root->right,key,val);
        }else{
            root->right=(intTree*) malloc(sizeof(intTree));
            if(!root->right){
                return 1;
            }
            root->right->key=key;
            root->right->val=val;
            root->right->left=0;
            root->right->right=0;
            return 0;
        }
    }
    if(key<root->key){
        if(root->left){
            return add(root->left,key,val);
        }else{
            root->left=malloc(sizeof(intTree));
            if(!root->left){
                return 1;
            }
            root->left->key=key;
            root->left->val=val;
            root->left->left=0;
            root->left->right=0;
            return 0;
        }
    }
    return 2;
}

void* get(intTree* root,int key){
    if(!root){
        return 0;
    }
    if(key>root->key){
        return get(root->right,key);
    }
    if(key<root->key){
        return get(root->left,key);
    }
    return root->val;
}

int remove_root(intTree* root){
    if(!root){
        return 1;
    }
    if(root->right){
        root->key=root->right->key;
        root->val=root->right->val;
        return remove_root(root->right);
    }
    if(root->left){
        root->key=root->left->key;
        root->val=root->left->val;
        return remove_root(root->left);
    }
    free(root);
    return 0;
}

int remove_node(intTree* root,int key){
    if(!root){
        return 1;
    }
    if(key>root->key){
        return remove_node(root->right,key);
    }
    if(key<root->key){
        return remove_node(root->left,key);
    }
    return remove_root(root);
}

void delete(intTree* root){
    if(root){
        delete(root->right);
        delete(root->left);
        free(root);
    }
}

void pretty_print(intTree* root,int ws,int wso,void (*print_val)(void*)){
    if(!root) return;
    printf("%*s",ws,"");
    print_val(root->val);
    pretty_print(root->left,ws+wso,wso,print_val);
    pretty_print(root->right,ws+wso,wso,print_val);
}
```

bintree.h

```
#pragma once

#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct intTree_s{
    int key;
    void* val;
    struct intTree_s* left;
    struct intTree_s* right;
} intTree;

int add(intTree*,int,void*);
void* get(intTree*,int);
int remove_root(intTree*);
int remove_node(intTree*,int);
void delete(intTree*);
void pretty_print(intTree*,int,int,void(*)(void*));
```

These throw hundreds of errors about intTree being an incomplete type.  This persists for whichever format of typedef/struct I use to define intTree.

bintree.c

```
#include "pretty_print.h"
void pretty_print(void){return;}
```

pretty_print.h

```
void pretty_print(void);
```

Throws conflicting types for "pretty_print", though it does not if I rename to "p", inline the header, or change the arguments to "int v".  This also works with the arguments "int* a,void(*)(void*)", as in the original program.

Final "error": warns about implicit redefinition of malloc, free, printf, and puts.

bintree.cxx

```
struct intTree_s{
    int key;
    void* val;
    struct intTree_s* left;
    struct intTree_s* right;
};

typedef struct intTree_s intTree;

int add(intTree* root,int key,void* val){
    if(!root){
        root=malloc(sizeof(intTree));
        if(!root){
            return 1;
        }
        root->key=key;
        root->val=val;
        root->left=0;
        root->right=0;
        return 0;
    }
    if(key>root->key){
        if(root->right){
            return add(root->right,key,val);
        }else{
            root->right=(intTree*) malloc(sizeof(intTree));
            if(!root->right){
                return 1;
            }
            root->right->key=key;
            root->right->val=val;
            root->right->left=0;
            root->right->right=0;
            return 0;
        }
    }
    if(key<root->key){
        if(root->left){
            return add(root->left,key,val);
        }else{
            root->left=malloc(sizeof(intTree));
            if(!root->left){
                return 1;
            }
            root->left->key=key;
            root->left->val=val;
            root->left->left=0;
            root->left->right=0;
            return 0;
        }
    }
    return 2;
}

void* get(intTree* root,int key){
    if(!root){
        return 0;
    }
    if(key>root->key){
        return get(root->right,key);
    }
    if(key<root->key){
        return get(root->left,key);
    }
    return root->val;
}

int remove_root(intTree* root){
    if(!root){
        return 1;
    }
    if(root->right){
        root->key=root->right->key;
        root->val=root->right->val;
        return remove_root(root->right);
    }
    if(root->left){
        root->key=root->left->key;
        root->val=root->left->val;
        return remove_root(root->left);
    }
    free(root);
    return 0;
}

int remove_node(intTree* root,int key){
    if(!root){
        return 1;
    }
    if(key>root->key){
        return remove_node(root->right,key);
    }
    if(key<root->key){
        return remove_node(root->left,key);
    }
    return remove_root(root);
}

void delete(intTree* root){
    if(root){
        delete(root->right);
        delete(root->left);
        free(root);
    }
}

void pretty_print(intTree* root,int ws,int wso,void (*print_val)(void*)){
    if(!root) return;
    printf("%*s",ws,"");
    print_val(root->val);
    pretty_print(root->left,ws+wso,wso,print_val);
    pretty_print(root->right,ws+wso,wso,print_val);
}
```

I can't seem to generate the original error, which was about a redefinition of pretty_print, again.  I apoligize for how little I know about this problem (basically just that it is).

Comment: too much code, way too much. Also, even when you fix the syntax errors, the code will suffer from several semantic ones (i. e. trying to assign `root` from within a function, etc.) - [furthermore, don't cast the return value of `malloc()`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc/605858#605858).

Comment: I do not agree with @user3477950 because with casting to the receiving pointer type, an error message can/will be generated about a type mismatch.

Comment: @user3629249 What? This is not subject to agreement/disagreement, this is a fact (and just read that answer). It seems that you don't know that `void *` is implicitly convertible to and from any pointer-to-object type. The cast is not necessary, it can hide errors, it introduces redundancy, and consequently it has no benefits but it has a risk of getting it wrong. So, don't do it. No decent C programmer does it.

Comment: I though I removed that!  Also, the code as shown leaks the void* in the intTree struct when delete() is called.  So it is still far from perfect.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> implicit redefinition of malloc, free, printf, and puts.

This means you're not including the proper header files.  Add these to every C file that calls these functions.

```
#include <stdio.h>      // printf, puts and friends
#include <stdlib.h>     // malloc/free
```

Don't put them in some common header file - only do that if they expose a *type* that you use in the header file itself.

You're getting an "implicit redefinition" because, if you don't include the proper header files, the compiler will *implicitly define* their signatures based upon your usage (the dumbest feature of C, IMO).

---

People seem to have a hard time knowing what goes in the `.c` file and the header files.  It's simple:

1. Start out putting everything related to this component (e.g your intTree implementation) in one `.c` file. (Including `struct`s). Mark all functions `static` which means they are not visible to anyone outside of the file.
2. Decide which functions are part of your publicly-accessible API. Remove `static` from these functions, and copy/paste their *prototype* to that `.c` file's accompanying `.h` file. (e.g. `int add(intTree* root,int key,void* val);`).
3. Decide if any `struct`s need to be visible as well, or if they can be hidden. It's best to leave the actual `struct` definition *hidden* in the .C file.  Your public API functions will take only *pointers to* those structures, so outside code will never need to know the size/offsets of those `struct`s.  So just add `struct foo;` to the header file, leaving its definition in the .C file.

Example:

**foo.c**

```
#include "foo.h"

/** Definition of struct foo - hidden to consumers of foo **/
struct foo
{
    int a;
    int b;
    int c;
};             /* This always gets forgotten :-) */

/** "private" internal function, marked static to hide from consumers **/
static void _foo_internal(struct foo *f)
{
    // ... internal function ****
}

/** Foo Public API **/
struct foo *new_foo(int a, int b, int c)
{
    struct foo* f;

    f = malloc(sizeof(*f));
    if (f == NULL)
        return NULL;

    _foo_internal(f);
    f->a = a;
    f->b = b;
    f->c = c;
}

int foo_get_a(struct foo *f)
{
    _foo_internal(f);
    return f->a;
}

void foo_set_a(struct foo *f, int val)
{
    _foo_internal(f);
    f->a = val;
}
```

**foo.h**

```
#ifndef FOO_H
#define FOO_H

/**
 * Consumers need to know only that struct foo exists,
 * not its size of member offsets.
 */
struct foo;

/** Prototypes for foo public API **/
struct foo *new_foo(int a, int b, int c);
int foo_get_a(struct foo *f);
void foo_set_a(struct foo *f, int val);

#endif /* FOO_H */
```

**test.c**

```
#include "foo.h"

int main(void)
{
    /**
     * No static instances of foo allowed!
     * test.c does not know the size of struct foo!
     */
    //struct foo my_foo;

    struct foo *pFoo;

    pFoo = new_foo(1,2,3);
    if (pFoo == NULL)
        return 1;

    set_foo_a(pFoo, 42);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you: using this I can get it to work in one file, but not with a header.  I have "struct intTree_s;typedef struct intTree_s intTree;" in the header and "struct intTree_s{...};" in the code, and I get hundreds of errors about intTree being an incomplete type.   Am I still doing it wrong?  Nevermind, I forgot the semicolon after the struct def.

Answer (score 1):

```
This typedef struct format your using is deprecated syntax.
rather, use:


struct intTree_s{
    int key;
    void* val;
    struct intTree_s* left;
    struct intTree_s* right;
};

Then on every reference to intTree_s, write it as: struct intTree_s
This will eliminate the 'incomplete struct' error messages
```